# Regex para pegar um texto entre <>

Tags: java, regex

Estou tentando pegar uma palavra entre `<>`. Por exemplo:

Texto: `"Joao <joao@email.com>"`

Meu regex deveria pegar `joao@email.com`, mas está pegando `<joao@email.com>`
O regex que estou usando é `<(.*?)>`.

Alguém sabe como retirar os `<>`?

Comment: Que linguagem está usando?

Comment: Dependendo da linguagem, é melhor usar operações normais de string em vez de RegEx.

Comment: @Bacco Usando Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alguém sabe como retirar os <>?

Sim, você tem que escapar eles.

Em java...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String texto = "Joao <joao@email.com>";
    String regex = "\\<(?<meuGrupo>.*?)\\>";
    String retorno = "";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);;
    Matcher comparator = pattern.matcher(texto);
    if (comparator.find(0)){
        retorno = comparator.group("meuGrupo");
    }

    System.out.println(retorno);
}
```

Comment: Boa solução! Usou regex e recursos da linguagem. Código ficou bom. Valeu!

Answer (score 4):

### Solução alternativa (sem RegEx)

Como o autor mencionou estar usando Java, fica uma resposta alternativa com *substring*, para quem possa ter interesse:

```
mail = mail.substring(mail.indexOf("<")+1,mail.indexOf(">"));
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/dugE8W)**.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar uma expressão que leia todos os caracteres **que não sejam o >**:

```
\<([^\>]+)\>
```

Um JSFiddle mostrando um exemplo com essa regex: http://jsfiddle.net/r1mfz24s/. Note que você não precisa escapar os `<` e o `>`, mas eu costumo escapar todos os caracteres especiais para evitar confusão.

Answer (score 1):

Para mim funcionou usando a expressão regular `<(.*)>`.

Usando o site http://regex101.com - ao testar esta expressão regular com o `Joao <joao@email.com>`, o que foi capturado foi só o `joao@email.com`.

Comment: Não sei se o AP tem strings com varios emails mas se tiver esta regex vai falhar https://regex101.com/r/uV1tQ7/1

Comment: @Sergio Sim, mas daí o AP deveria especificar direito o que é que ele vai receber ou não.

Comment: Sim, a pergunta tem essa falha e ainda não especificar a linguagem. Vamos ver se o AP edita e junta mais info. (ah, vi agora que está nos comments)